# Why does this printf output 27 repeatedly?

Tags: php, printf, range

```
<?php

$letters = range(A,Z);

$format_string = '<li><a href="#%s">%s</a></li>';

foreach ($letters as $key => $letter) {
    echo printf($format_string,$letter, $letter);
}

?>
```

This is meant to print out an li with the alphabet from A-W, however the output looks like this:

- A

  27
- B

  27

etc.. all the way up to the last number.

Using a regular echo with string concatenation outputs the list fine without any 27's.

Comment: check quotes => range('A','Z');

Comment: What does `printf` return according to the docs? Why are you printing it?

Comment: You're looking for [sprintf](https://getcomposer.org/) not printf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `echo` with the return value of the call to `printf`, which is defined in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) as

> Returns the length of the outputted string.

So your `printf` call is running, and displaying your string. This is returning *27*, which is the length of the string `<li><a href="#%s">%s</a></li>` once a single letter has been inserted into it. The call to `echo` is then displaying that after the string itself has been shown.

In short, either remove `echo` or as mentioned in a comment, use `sprintf` instead, which returns the string instead of displaying it.